# Detect color from image for overlay text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, detection

im loking for some category/subclass to detect a color for overlay text (UILabel), so the text can be readable.

Any advice?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I think you might be setting it programatically.

Comment: depend how do you create the class? post some code

Comment: What i need is, that under text is a UIImage, and i need to get opposite color for UILabel, so the text is readable.